# Why is an article present here?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

I took a test on articles and scored 84%. Unfortunately, the site provides no explanation as to why I was wrong, so I kindly ask for your help here.

> Kumiko discovered that there were quite a few cultural differences between the Danish and Norwegians. She had always assumed Scandinavians were the same.

I used 'the Scandinavians' instead of 'Scandinavians' because I though it was referring to a class. Can anybody explain why, unlike 'the Danish and Norwegians', there should be no article?

EDIT:

Thanks for all your help. What helped the most was the thread at http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/definite-article-with-nationalities.1021920/—especially, this part: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmT5A.jpg.

Comment: The English vs Americans, the Danish vs Norwegians/Scandinavians. Cheese is a mass noun. You don't need to put an article before it.

Comment: Articles can be used with uncountables when they represent a class, right? I.E. The water is slowly evaporating on Earth. And your I did not get your Danish vs Scandinavians part at all.

Comment: What do you mean by a "class"? All those words are referring to a general population of a country.

Comment: Okay, my question still stands open - why the is used with 'the Danish and Norwegians' and not used with 'Scandinavians'

Comment: Now I see where your confusion comes from. In "the Danish and Norwegians", "the" only determines "Danish", not Norwegians.

Comment: The *the* distributes.

Comment: It would distribute if one were not _contrasting_ Danish with Norwegians.  But since it is a contrast, there is an argument for using **the** before Norwegians.  It would certainly be clearer.  As for Scandinavians, I would preface with **all**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly 2 different ways to describe a general population of each country: "the + *Adjective* and "Noun + s".

When you use the Danish/English/Chinese/Japanese, etc. "Danish and others" are not a "noun", but an "adjective".

It is a short form of "the Danish (people)" and you use "the *Adjective*" form because it can represent a general population of an *Adjective* country.

It is different from using Americans/Norwegians/Scandinavians (or Danes for the Danish) as their nouns end with "n or ne".

You can visit this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_English) and [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_people) see how "the English" and "Danes" are used.

> ***The English*** are a nation and ethnic group native to England, who speak the English language. The English identity is of early mediaeval
>   origin, when they were known in Old English as the Angelcynn ("family
>   of the Angles").

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've found an answer.

According to http://www.englishpage.com/articles/advanced-articles.htm p. 21, the is used  to differentiate between an adjective and a noun since 'Danish' can be a noun as well as an adj.

Comment: Yes, but the sentence is using Scandinavians/Norwegians (plural) so it cannot be an adjective unless I'm mistaken here, while  both the singular and plural forms are the same for Danish (no Danishes).

Comment: @Sam _Danishes_ are pastries, so a different thing. That said, using _Danish_ here at all is clumsy an awkward; _Danes_ would sound much more natural.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that referring to "the Scandinavians" as a class changes the meaning of the sentence.  When you say

> She had always assumed **the** Scandinavians were the same.

you leave your reader wondering what other class of non-Nordic people are the same as the Scandinavians.  Perhaps

> She had always assumed **the** Scandinavians were the same as **the** Chinese.

But that's not what she's assuming.  She's assuming that *individual* Scandinavians, whether of Danish or of Norwegian nationality, are the same because they are grouped together and labeled Scandinavians.

Comment: Your version does not fit the one I found, could you please check my answer and tell me why it's wrong? Thanks. P.S. I am going to take IELTS test, and so I'm trying to improve my knowledge of articles because they've always been my weak spot.

Comment: Personally, whether there's an article or not, I'm left wondering what it is the Danes and Norwegians are also. For the meaning intended, they ought to have added an _all-: “She'd always assumed (the) Danes and (the) Norwegians were all the same” is fine to me, but as it stands now, it's very unclearly worded.

Comment: @Sam Didn't you accept the top answer?  Still not satisfied?  Well, OK. Your answer doesn't tell you what you want to know. Replace "the Danish" with *the Danes*; replace "Norwegians" with *the Norwegians*.  *Scandinavians* still can't take an article.

Comment: Yes it can. It needs "all".  To clarify exactly the problem you mentioned—same as **what**?  Same as **each other**!

Answer (score 0):

To understand why you can't use *the* there, you have to realize that both Danish and Norwegians are Scandinavians.

If you say *"the Danish"*, *"the Norwegians"*, *"the Scandinavians"*, this is talking about Danes, Norwegians, or Scandinavians as a unitary class. But this sentence says that two subclasses of Scandinavians are different, so it's not treating *Scandinavians* as a unitary class, so you cannot use *"the"*. What it means is that

> She had always assumed all Scandinavians were the same.